# Mean value theorem

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives

I have a small question:

> We consider the existence of multiple solutions of the periodic boundary value problem $$\ddot{u}(t)+\nabla F(t,u(t))=0\\
> u(0)-u(T)=\dot{u}(0)-\dot u(T)=0\tag{8}$$
>   where $F\in \text C^2([0,T]\times \mathbf R^{N}, \mathbf R)$ satisfies the conditions $$\varphi(u)=\int_0^T[(1/2)|\dot u(t)|^2-F(t,u(t))]\,\mathrm dt$$
>   Let us also define the operator $L$ and the functional $\psi$ on $H^1_T$ by $$((Lu,v))=\int_0^T(\dot u(t)-A_\infty(t)u(t),v(t))\,\mathrm dt \\ \psi(u)=\varphi(u)-(1/2)((Lu,u)).$$

why does the mean value theorem give us: $$|\psi(u)|\leq \int_0^T ((\nabla \psi (su),u)) ds +|\psi(0)|$$

Thank you

($A_0$ and $A_{\infty}$ are symetric matrix )

Comment: This question needs clarificatoins. Please add some context such as the assumptions on $\psi$.